# MySQL: sum session times via students, via program

Tags: mysql

I have the following:

```
Programs     Students      Sessions
--------     ----------    ----------
id           id            id
name         program_id    student_id
...          ...           time_in
                           time_out
```

Programs have many students, students have many sessions. Each session has a duration, delineated by `time_in` and `time_out`.

What I want is a summary of total hours students spent in sessions by program. So an example result would look like:

```
Results:

Program Name       hours
-----------        ---------
Nursing            300 hours
Pharmacy           467 hours
PT                 598 hours
```

After much scrounging, I have the following query:

```
SELECT programs.name, a.session_sum FROM(
    SELECT students.program_id AS stu_id, 
    TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(time_out, time_in)) AS session_sum
    FROM students INNER JOIN sessions
    ON students.id = sessions.student_id
    GROUP BY students.program_id
) AS a, programs
WHERE programs.id = a.stu_id
```

It works...sort of. Unfortunately, it only seems to work for the *first* session found for a given student and not *all* the sessions that student might have.

I'm at the edge of my MySQL knowledge getting this far. What am I missing? Should I scrap this query and go in an entirely different direction? I can also resort to looping in Rails, but I'd like to figure out a way to do things with a single query.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your inner SQL Statement:

```
SELECT students.program_id AS stu_id, 
TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(time_out, time_in)) AS session_sum
FROM students INNER JOIN sessions
ON students.id = sessions.student_id
GROUP BY students.program_id
```

You `GROUP BY students.program_id` but you don't give any aggregate function for your `session_sum` and this case MY SQL's default behaviour is that you only get the first result (Remark: MS SQL Server would throw an error in such a case).

So

```
SELECT students.program_id AS stu_id, 
SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(time_out, time_in))) AS session_sum
FROM students INNER JOIN sessions
ON students.id = sessions.student_id
GROUP BY students.program_id
```

should work. But I don't have a MY SQL at the hand right now to try. And by the way, to do it in really a single query, this should work, too (but I can't try right now).

```
SELECT 
   programs.name, 
   SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(sessions.time_out, sessions.time_in))) AS session_sum 
FROM
   programs LEFT JOIN students ON programs.id = students.program_id
            INNER JOIN sessions ON students.id = sessions.student_id
GROUP BY programs.id
```

Comment: Thanks! This was the problem. Oh, so obvious after it's been pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Why does the Students table contain `program ID`? The students table is primarily meant to carry information about students. What you're doing seems to also be capturing relationship between students and programs in the same table, which brings me to the question if a student is only in one program for life.

Instead, why not have the program ID in sessions table? This way you wont need to join 3 tables. I would happily associate a session with a program ID.